# How to retrieve records from database by selecting a list item

Tags: android

Hi i want to select an item from list box and to retrieve the records of the selected item from the database display its content  in edittext field. Iam new to android and i can't found any hints regarding to this topic. so friends if anybody knows please help me.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: provide some code and what you have tried?

Comment: i can retrieve the record from the database..but dont know how to implement it using list box

Comment: first search in google and then post your question here because using above information no one can help you.

Comment: i surfed google,in that there are links for other programming languages. please help me with some code Or give me a hint to do like that

Answer (score 0):

The listbox you are referring to is called a [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) in Android.

Retrieve your data in `onItemSelected()`.